# Adapter pattern to support multiple file storage systems

Tags: php, object-oriented, design-patterns, file-system, network-file-transfer

I am just getting into the following design patterns.

I have created a class that allows for performing a couple of operations on different remote storage systems: drive, dropbox, .etc (I call these `drivers` although there might be a better name). The main class accepts the driver whether it be one of the previous, and uses common methods to perform actions. All of the drivers conform to an interface.

- Am I using the adapter pattern correctly?
- Are there any things I should take into consideration to improve my code?

```
    <?php
    
    namespace RestorePoint\Adapters;
    
    use RestorePoint\Adapters\RemoteFilesDriver\RemoteFilesDriverInterface;
    use RestorePoint\Traits\FilesystemTrait;
    use RestorePoint\Helpers\Benchmark;
    use RestorePoint\Exception;
    use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Options;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;
    use Cake\Filesystem\File;
    
    final class RemoteStorageAdapter {
    
        use FilesystemTrait;
    
        public $options;
        private $driver;
        private $driverClass;
        private $benchmark;
        private $log;
    
        public function __construct(RemoteFilesDriverInterface $driver, Benchmark $benchmark, LoggerInterface $log, array $options = []) {
            $this->benchmark = $benchmark;
            $this->driver = $driver;
            $this->log = $log;
            $resolver = new OptionsResolver();
            $resolver->setDefined(array_keys($options));
            $this->configureOptions($resolver);
            $this->options = $resolver->resolve($options);
            $this->driverClass = $this->driver->handle();
        }
    
        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
            $resolver->setDefaults([
                'uploadCheckQuota' => true,
                'cleanup' => true,
                'backupAmountRemote' => null,
                'uploadChunkSize' => 1024 * 1024 * 5,
                'uploadFileSizeLimit' => -1,
            ]);
            $resolver
                    ->setRequired('backupFolderName')
                    ->setAllowedTypes('backupAmountRemote', ['null', 'int'])
                    ->setAllowedTypes('uploadCheckQuota', 'boolean')
                    ->setAllowedTypes('cleanup', 'boolean')
                    ->setAllowedTypes('backupFolderName', 'string')
                    ->setAllowedTypes('uploadChunkSize', 'int');
            $resolver->setNormalizer('backupAmountRemote', function (Options $options, $value) {
                if ($options['cleanup'] == true && is_null($value)) {
                    throw new InvalidArgumentException(__CLASS__ . ': When cleanup is true, backupAmountRemote cannot be null.');
                }
                return $value;
            });
        }
        
        /**
         * __call
         * 
         * @param string $method
         * @param array $arguments
         * @throws Exception
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function __call($method, $arguments) {
            if (method_exists($this->driver, $method)) {
                return call_user_func_array(array($this->driver, $method), $arguments);
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Method {$method} does not exist in {$this->driverClass}");
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * Get service folder
         * 
         * @return string
         */
        public function getFolder() {
            if (($folder = $this->driver->folderExists($this->options['backupFolderName'])) === FALSE) {
                $folder = $this->driver->makeFolder($this->options['backupFolderName']);
            }
            return $folder;
        }
    
        /**
         * Adds files available locally to the service
         * This WILL NOT delete old files on the server
         * 
         * @param string $localDir Full path to local files folder
         * @return boolean
         * @throws Exception
         */
        public function sync($localDir) {
            $folder = $this->getFolder();
            $localFiles = $this->listFilesByCreated($localDir);
            $remoteFiles = $this->driver->listFilesByCreated($folder);
            $localFilesCol = array_column($localFiles, 'name');
            foreach ($remoteFiles as $key => $value) {
                $index = array_search($value['name'], $localFilesCol);
                if ($index !== false) {
                    unset($localFiles[$index]);
                }
            }
            $ct = count($localFiles);
            $this->log->debug("Sync determined {$ct} files should be added to {$this->driverClass}.");
            if ($ct == 0) {
                return false;
            }
            foreach ($localFiles as $file) {
                $this->log->debug($this->driverClass . ': Attempting to add ' . $file['name'] . '...');
                $this->uploadFile($localDir . $file['name']);
            }
            return $ct;
        }
    
        /**
         * Will remove old backup files on the server according to backupAmt
         * 
         * The oldest files are the ones furthest in the past that were uploaded to the server.
         * If you have backupAmt set to 1 and just added a backup to the remote folder from 2015,
         * while having a backup file from 2019 on the server, the file from 2015 will technically
         * be the newest file, and thus the one from 2019 will be deleted. 
         * 
         * This is due to APIs marking the time the file was created as the time they were uploaded,
         * despite that not being the time the file was actually generated.
         * 
         * Under normal circumstances, if your local and remote systems maintain sync, this point
         * is not of much concern. Just keep this in mind.
         * 
         * @return int Files removed
         * @throws Exception
         */
        public function cleanup() {
            $folder = $this->getFolder();
            $i = 0;
            if (is_null($this->options['backupAmountRemote'])) {
                $this->log->info("{$this->driverClass}: backupAmountRemote is null. Calling cleanup will have no effect.");
                return $i;
            }
            $files = $this->driver->listFilesByCreated($folder);
            $files = array_slice($files, $this->options['backupAmountRemote']);
            $ct = count($files);
            if ($ct > 0) {
                $this->log->debug("{$this->driverClass}: Cleanup determined {$ct} files should be removed remotely.");
                foreach ($files as $file) {
                    $this->log->debug($this->driverClass . ': Attempting to delete ' . $file['name'] . '...');
                    $this->driver->deleteFile($file['id']);
                    $this->log->debug($this->driverClass . ': ' . $file['name'] . ' successfully deleted.');
                    $i++;
                }
            }
            return $i;
        }
    
        /**
         * Upload file to service
         * 
         * @param string $file The file to upload
         * @return string Name and ext of file uploaded
         * @throws Exception
         */
        public function uploadFile($file) {
            ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);
            $folder = $this->getFolder();
            $file = new File($file);
            if ($this->driver->fileExists($file->name, $folder)) {
                throw new Exception("{$this->driverClass}: {$file->name} already exists.");
            }
            if ($this->options['uploadCheckQuota']) {
                $this->hasSpace($file->size());
            }
            if ($this->options['uploadFileSizeLimit'] > 0 && $file->size() > $this->options['uploadFileSizeLimit']) {
                throw new Exception("{$this->driverClass}: It is likely the script will take too long to complete. Backup file is too big at {$file->size()} bytes to be uploaded to the service.");
            }
            $this->benchmark->mark('uploadStart');
            $ret = $this->driver->addFile($file, $folder, $this->options['uploadChunkSize']);
            $elapsedTime = $this->benchmark->elapsedTime('uploadStart');
            $this->log->debug("{$this->driverClass}: File {$file->name} successfully added. Task took {$elapsedTime} seconds.");
            return $ret;
        }
    
        /**
         * Checks if a file can be added to service based on its size and the quota available
         * 
         * @param int $fileSize Bytes
         * @return void
         * @throws Exception
         */
        private function hasSpace($fileSize) {
            $spaceRemaining = $this->driver->getSpaceRemaining();
            if ($spaceRemaining === -1) {
                return; // -1 = driver doesn't support this command
            }
            if ($spaceRemaining - $fileSize <= 0) {
                throw new Exception("{$this->driverClass}: Not enough space for {$fileSize} bytes. Only {$spaceRemaining} bytes available.");
            }
        }
    
    }
```

So as to avoid posting too much code, here is the interface all of the drivers follow:

```
    <?php
    
    namespace RestorePoint\Adapters\RemoteFilesDriver;
    
    use RestorePoint\Adapters\Service\ServiceInterface;
    use Cake\Filesystem\File;
    
    interface RemoteFilesDriverInterface {
    
        public function __construct(ServiceInterface $service);
    
        /**
         * Should return a human name version of the driver
         * 
         * @return string
         */
        public function handle();
    
        /**
         * Simply checks if a file exists remotely
         * 
         * @param string $file
         * @param string $folder
         * @return boolean
         */
        public function fileExists($file, $folder);
    
        /**
         * Deletes a remote file
         * 
         * @param string $file
         * @throws Exception
         */
        public function deleteFile($file);
    
        /**
         * Check if a folder exists, if so, return ID or path
         * 
         * @param string $folder
         * @return mixed The ID or path of the folder
         */
        public function folderExists($folder);
    
        /**
         * Makes folder and returns folder ID or path
         * 
         * @param string $folder
         * @return mixed The ID or path of the folder
         */
        public function makeFolder($folder);
    
        /**
         * Gets free space - used space
         * 
         * @return int
         * @throws Exception
         */
        public function getSpaceRemaining();
    
        /**
         * Lists files in order from newest to oldest
         * Conforms file to an associative array with keys
         * name, id, created
         * 
         * Name: somefile.zip
         * Id: /path/to/file or 123123
         * Created: timestamp representation of date created
         * 
         * @param mixed $folder ID or path of folder
         * @return array
         * @throws Exception
         */
        public function listFilesByCreated($folder);
    
        /**
         * Uploads a file to remote service
         * 
         * @param File $file Instance of Cake\Filesystem\File
         * @param mixed $folder Path or ID of folder
         * @param int $chunkSizeBytes
         * @return string filename
         * @throws Exception
         */
        public function addFile(File $file, $folder, $chunkSizeBytes);
        
        /**
         * Not yet implemented
         * 
         * @param mixed $file
         * @param string $destination
         */
        public function download($file, $destination);
    }
```

I would also argue, based on my understanding, that the drivers themselves are adapters for the service libraries they implement (Google Client Services, Dropbox API) to get a predefined output. But I am unsure of this.

update:

[Here is an example driver](https://pastebin.com/9QEyHZ8f)

Comment: ... or is it a strategy pattern??

Comment: Would it be better to use `interface` rather than `if (method_exists(`?

Answer (score 2):

The code looks very well documented. It makes good use of type declarations for arguments.

> *Are there any things I should take in to consideration to improve my code?*

## Follow PHP Standards Recommendations

While there are no *de jure* rules about readability conventions and it is up to individuals/teams to decide their conventions, idiomatic PHP code often follows the [PHP Standards Recommendations](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/) - e.g. [PSR-12: Extended Coding Style](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/), which replaced the deprecated [PSR-2: Coding Style Guide](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) 9 days after the code here was posted. The code presented follows many of the recommendations though not all.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 23 ERRORS AND 5 WARNINGS AFFECTING 26 LINES
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   1 | ERROR   | [x] End of line character is invalid; expected "\n"
     |         |     but found "\r\n"
  15 | ERROR   | [x] Opening brace of a class must be on the line
     |         |     after the definition
  25 | WARNING | [ ] Line exceeds 120 characters; contains 134
     |         |     characters
  25 | ERROR   | [x] Opening brace should be on a new line
  36 | ERROR   | [x] Opening brace should be on a new line
  53 | WARNING | [ ] Line exceeds 120 characters; contains 125
     |         |     characters
  61 | ERROR   | [x] Whitespace found at end of line
  67 | ERROR   | [x] Opening brace should be on a new line
  77 | ERROR   | [x] Whitespace found at end of line
  80 | ERROR   | [x] Opening brace should be on a new line
  81 | ERROR   | [x] TRUE, FALSE and NULL must be lowercase; expected
     |         |     "false" but found "FALSE"
  90 | ERROR   | [x] Whitespace found at end of line
  95 | ERROR   | [x] Opening brace should be on a new line
 120 | ERROR   | [x] Whitespace found at end of line
 124 | ERROR   | [x] Whitespace found at end of line
 125 | ERROR   | [x] Whitespace found at end of line
 128 | ERROR   | [x] Whitespace found at end of line
 131 | ERROR   | [x] Whitespace found at end of line
 135 | ERROR   | [x] Opening brace should be on a new line
 159 | ERROR   | [x] Whitespace found at end of line
 164 | ERROR   | [x] Opening brace should be on a new line
 175 | WARNING | [ ] Line exceeds 120 characters; contains 192
     |         |     characters
 180 | WARNING | [ ] Line exceeds 120 characters; contains 124
     |         |     characters
 186 | ERROR   | [x] Whitespace found at end of line
 191 | ERROR   | [x] Opening brace should be on a new line
 197 | WARNING | [ ] Line exceeds 120 characters; contains 137
     |         |     characters
 201 | ERROR   | [x] Expected 1 newline at end of file; 0 found
 201 | ERROR   | [x] The closing brace for the class must go on the
     |         |     next line after the body
```

## Return type declarations can be added

Presuming the code is running on PHP 7 or later, [return type declarations for the methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.return-type-declarations) can be added.

## Use strict equality comparisons

[It is a good habit to use strict equality operators](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/126585/244085) whenever possible. There are three occurrences of strict equality comparison operators (e.g. `===`) used, though some conditional statements use loose equality operators - i.e. `==`.

> ```
> if ($options['cleanup'] == true && is_null($value)) {
> ```

Most idiomatic PHP code would simply use `$options['cleanup']` instead of `($options['cleanup'] == true`.

> ```
> $ct = count($localFiles);
> if ($ct == 0) {
>      return false;
> }
> ```

[`count()`](https://www.php.net/count) returns an integer so strict equality could be used there also, though again idiomatic PHP code would typically just use `if (!$ct)`.

## Keyword `else` can be avoided in some cases

In the `__call()` method there is a check to see if the method exists:

> ```
>    if (method_exists($this->driver, $method)) {
>        return call_user_func_array(array($this->driver, $method), $arguments);
>    } else {
>        throw new Exception("Method {$method} does not exist in {$this->driverClass}");
>    }
> ```

It could be simplified to not need the `else` and decrease the indentation level of the `return` statement by flipping the logic flow:

```
    if (!method_exists($this->driver, $method)) {
        throw new Exception("Method {$method} does not exist in {$this->driverClass}");
    } 
    return call_user_func_array(array($this->driver, $method), $arguments);
```

## Some documentation is not always correct

The docblock for `sync` shows:

> ```
>     /**
>     * Adds files available locally to the service
>     * This WILL NOT delete old files on the server
>    * 
>    * @param string $localDir Full path to local files folder
>    * @return boolean
>    * @throws Exception
>    */
> ```

Within the method there is a place where a boolean can be returned:

> ```
> if ($ct == 0) {
>     return false;
> }
> ```

Yet later at the end of the method the return statement is:

> ```
> return $ct;
> ```

Where `$ct` was assigned the integer returned from calling `count`. Thus the method can return a boolean or an integer. If the code is running on PHP 8 or later then the [`mixed` type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.mixed.php) could be used in the method's type declaration.

## Manually incrementing in `cleanup` seems superfluous

The `cleanup` method appears to attempt to delete files and at the end of the `foreach` loop increments `$i` which is returned at the end of the method. It appears there is no code to handle exceptions so if a file was not deleted then `$i` would still get incremented. Unless I am missing something it can simply return `$ct` like the `sync` method does, and there is no reason to declare and increment `$i`.